# integrating a freemind map into the web application

Tags: export, freemind

I created a mind map using the tool and now I want to embed the map in my web application. I tried to do export as html and it converts the map into a list.
I want to be able to view the map as it is in the browser, i.e. clickable ovals.

In addition to this I want to be able to pass a variable to the mind map (like username) which will be used in node text.

How do I achieve these?

Thanks in advance
Priyank

Answer (score 1):

I use freemind quit often but have never tried the exporting option...however if you go to Help -> Documentation...There is some helpful info... p.s. below screenshot

[image: Screenshot of FreeMind documentation]

Comment: Thanks, but right now I am getting this error after exporting as XHTML (javascript version) and placing it in the application : "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/gra/freemind.main.FreeMindApplet.class", I have the jar in the same folder and also in the lib directory of the project